Recurring notifications at set time (expo-notifications)
I'm trying to set up recurring notifications at a set time.
Daily, weekly, monthly.
On iOS and Android. I'm testing on Android.
Here's the code I'm using to set daily notifications:
await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
    content: notificationContent,
    trigger: {
        hour: hour,
        minute: minute,
        repeats: true,
        channelId: 'medication',
    },
});

With the above, I can set a notification that shows at the specified time. But, if I change my system time to the next day, 1 min before, and wait... nothing appears. What am I doing wrong, and is this the correct approach to test this?
Someone on the expo developers Discord suggested adding seconds to the trigger, neither this nor second works on Android and is not in the documentation anyway.

Hi @Joseph, your code is correct. However, if you change the system time before the notification occurs, the notification may not trigger as expected. This is because the system relies on real-time data, and changing the time after scheduling the notification can disrupt its behavior. Please try scheduling the notification without changing the system time to verify if it triggers correctly.

@RushiDave you're absolutely right. The notification came through again today at the specified time (+1 day). Thanks!

Glad to hear it worked as expected! If you encounter any other issues or need further assistance, feel free to reach out. Happy to help!
